# Separate or Combine 2 Tables with Similar Attributes?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have two kind of users in my business system: **Customer** and **Employee**.
Both user have *Username*, *Password*, *Fullname*, *Phone Number*, *Email*, and other similar attributes.

> I have a difficulty to determine which is  better to merge
>   **Customer** and **Employee** on one table (for example I store in **User** table) or separate each entities on different table?

On my case, the **Customer** has additional attributes that the **Employee** doesn't had (for example: *NewsUpdateSubscription*). And also for **Employee**, it has additional attributes that **Customer** doesn't had (for example: *Salary*). What is the best practice for this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say "Customer" and "Employee" are two roles a person can play in your system. Thus, I'd add concept of "Role" to your design. Then you can store customer related attributes in one table, and employee related attributes in another. You will have something like

```
User (user_id, name, ...)
Role (role_id, description)
UserRole (user_role_id, user_id,role_id, date_from, date_thru) 
-- note, dates are quite important(at least date_from should be not null)
CustomerRoleAttribute(user_role_id, NewsUpdateSubscription)
EmployeeRoleAttribute(user_role_id, salary)
```

Also, to be absolutely correct, `Customer` and `Employee` roles require second part - for instance, I'm a customer of `AAA` company, and an employee of `BBB`, so my role is defined by relationship of certain type with other user (which is organization in case of "Employment" relationship).

You can find out more about this approach in "The Data Model Resource Book" by Len Silverston

Comment: Thanks a1ex07, do we need primary key again on **CustomerRoleAttribute** & **EmployeeRoleAttribute** since user_role_id is foreign key from **UserRole**? I mean, do we need something like CustomerID & EmployeeID since each table need primary key?

Comment: `user_role_id` can be primary key in those tables.

Answer (score 4):

While the names for these attributes may be the same, it's very likely that you'll want to store different values depending upon whether a person is a customer or an employee.

For example, if I work for a company but also use their website to purchase their products (so I'm an employee and a customer), when purchasing products I'll want to enter my personal phone number, email address etc. Whereas my employee record will need to store my work issued email address, phone and so on.

If you create a single `users` table to store all the common fields, if I want to change my contact number for purchases I've made, then my employee record will also be updated. If HR/IT use this information to know which phone I should return when leaving the company it could cause issues down the line if I'm free to change it in the customer context.

Therefore I'd recommend creating separate tables. The exception would be if you were in the unusual situation where your employees are your customers (which may be the case for an internal purchases application).

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris :), what is your opinion about the same field (username and password for login to the system)? Is it a normal form to create 2 tables with nearly similar attributes? I mean why not put it on User table then map it to Customer and Employee table. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your business rules for passwords are likely to be very different for customers and employees. Many companies have a policy requiring employees to change their password every 3-6 months; very few web applications I've used do the same. Managing the password rules around someone who is both an employee and a customer will get complex and confusing if managed using the same record. If entities have similar attributes but are subject to completely different rules and constraints, then it's perfectly valid to have two tables with similar fields.